# How to apply the border-radius prop of the children?

Tags: css

I have three div's in a parent wrapper. When I apply `border-radius:20px;` on the parent I get rounded borders. But when I apply a specific corner rounding on the child div's nothing happens. See the code below:

My Html:

```html
<nav id='sliderNav'>
  <div id='sliderDiv'>
    <ul id='slider'>
      <li>
        <img src='bookaparty.jpg' width='290' height='417' />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src='bottledeals.jpg' width='290' height='417' />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='slider3Div'>
    <ul id='slider3'>
      <li>
        <img src='bookaparty.jpg' width='290' height='417' />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src='bottledeals.jpg' width='290' height='417' />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='slider2Div'>
    <ul id='slider2'>
      <li>
        <img src='bookaparty.jpg' width='290' height='417' />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src='bottledeals.jpg' width='290' height='417' />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My Css:

```css
#sliderNav {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:0;
}

#sliderDiv { 
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
}

#slider2Div {
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}

#slider3Div {
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
}

#sliderNav div {
  font-size:18px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

This doesn't work, but if I change to the following I get every corner rounded:

```css
#sliderNav div {
  font-size:18px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time try creating a jsFiddle so we can see your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to recommend using shorthand for `border-radius` (which, if using PIE.htc, will work in IE8 and below):

**NOTE:** `border-radius` shorthand is as follows: `border-radius: top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left`

```
#sliderDiv{ 
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
#slider2Div{
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
#slider3Div{
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
```

Few reasons why I like to use shorthand:

1. Required for PIE.htc ([css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com))
2. The syntax for each corner is atrocious and different for each prefix (e.g. `border-top-left-radius` vs. `-moz-border-radius-topleft`).

Comment: Thank you, However this does not fix the problem. with border-radius set on the parent i get border rounding with it set on the child i get no rounding... Why, how can i fix this.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @AAronB Do you require additional assistance? Were you able to get it to work? My example works how it's supposed to. The only issue I had was when I didn't specify a `height`.